# How do I construct a nontrivial linear representation of the group $G$=S' in $R^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

$S'$ is defined as the unit circle. The product is defined as the sum of angles.

How do I construct a linear representation in general? I don't know how to begin with this problem. Some clarification about linear representations would be have much help.

**My thoughts**

I need to construct a homomorphism with some other additional properties. Define $\rho$ to be a homomorphism. I was thinking perhaps a linear transformation could be this homomorphism.

My guess is $\matrix{cos\alpha & -sin\alpha & cos\alpha \cr sin\alpha & cos\alpha & -sin\alpha \cr -cos\alpha & sin\alpha &cos\alpha}$

Would that work?

Comment: Try rotation matrices in 2D

Comment: A remark, thus unit circle is generally denoted $S^1$, not $S'$ (I guess the $'$ is supposed to be a $1$ but written badly).

Answer (score 1):

The circle group has a natural action by rotations in a real vector space of dimension $2$. Here your have dimension$~3$, and you must essentially choose to waste that extra dimension. More precisely, there has to be a line through the origin whose vectors are fixed by all linear operators of your representation (this can be formally proved, though I won't do so here); this is an "axis". So you need to decide which line to chose as axis, and then choose a complementary plane to that axis in which you will effect your rotation. There is a lot of freedom, but choosing everything as straightforwardly as possible you can easily define an explicit representation by rotations in dimension$~3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a matrix of the form

$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

has a natural action on $\Bbb R^2 \oplus \Bbb R$ as:

$\left(\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)^T,0\right) + ((0,0),z)$

and has the same determinant as the $2\times 2$ matrix in the upper-left.